# Extract specific part of text from large text which contains special charaters and multiple lines too

Tags: java, regex

Sample text is as follows

> DDS Implementation Statement of Work 
>   Allegis Group 
>   This Statement of Work ( SOW ) dated effective this 12
>   th
>    day of November, 2015, is attached to and 
>   forms part of the Service Agreement (the  Agreement ) between Absolute Software, Inc. ( Absolute ) 
>   and Allegis Group, Inc. ( Customer ), and is subject to the terms in the Service Agreement. Words and 
>   phrases defined in the Agreement have the same meaning when used in this SOW. 
>   1. Background 
>   Customer has installed and rendered successfully operating a number of devices for users at Customer s 
>   facilities. Included on each device, among a number of other software applications, is Absolute s patented 
>   DDS  technology.
>   Customer has initiated a project to detect devices on which the Pulse VPN client is not installed, and to 
>   automatically install/reinstall Pulse VPN on those devices by means of custom DDS agent scripting. 
>   2. Project Overview 
>   2.1. Customer is managing the project s overall scope, schedule and budget. Absolute s resources 
>   will be provided to assist with specific activities for a pre-determined amount of time. 
>   2.2. Absolute will provide a project leader to organize and manage execution of Absolute s scope of 
>   responsibilities on this project. Absolute s project leader will work with Customer s project 
>   manager to ensure the inter-dependencies between Absolute and Customer activities are 
>   coordinated for the optimum outcomes. 
>   2.3. Services provided as part of this SOW will be performed by Absolute at its corporate facilities. 
>   3. Project Scope and Deliverables 
>   3.1. During the various phases of the project, Absolute will provide the following services and 
>   deliverables:

From this text i want extract the text between

```
(the  Agreement ) between Absolute Software, Inc. ( Absolute ) and
Allegis Group, Inc. ( Customer )
```

I have used this regex
`(Agreement(”|\")\\)\\s?between(.*?)\\(“(.*)”\\)\\s?and\\s?(.*)\\((“|\")(Customer|Client)(”|\")\\))` but I'm unable to extract the text.

Comment: Your text has no double quotes.

Comment: yes there i am able to figure it out (Agreement(”|\")?\\s*\\)\\s*between\\s*(.*?)\\(“?(.*)”?\\)\\s*?and\\s*?(.*)\\(\\s*(“|\")?(Customer|Client)(”|\")?\\s*\\))

Answer (score 0):

You need find index key words in text using `indexOf` method and after that extract text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "DDS Implementation Statement of Work Allegis Group This Statement of Work ( SOW ) dated " +
        "effective this 12 th day of November, 2015, is attached to and forms part of the Service Agreement (the " +
        "Agreement ) between Absolute Software, Inc. ( Absolute ) and Allegis Group, Inc. ( Customer ), and is " +
        "subject to the terms in the Service Agreement. Words and phrases defined in the Agreement have the same " +
        "meaning when used in this SOW. 1.";

    String textFrom = "(the Agreement )";
    String textEnd = "( Customer )";
    int startIndex = text.indexOf(textFrom);
    int endIndex = text.indexOf(textEnd);

    String substring = text.substring(startIndex + textFrom.length(), endIndex);

    System.out.println(substring);
}
```